# Вернуть id из фрейма после проверки

Tags: python, pandas

```
# Получаю список статусов
get_data_from_first_table = """
                SELECT id,pas_id, date_add, status_id
                FROM table_1
                where status_id !=7
                and date_add>= now()- interval '10 day'
                order by date_add asc limit 50"""
cur.execute(get_data_from_first_table)
data_frame_from_first_table = cur.fetchall()

# преобразую в фрейм, группируя по pas_id
data_frame_from_first_table_to_frame = pd.DataFrame(data_frame_from_first_table, columns=['id','pas_id','date_add','status_id'])

# преобразую статусы в список
status_from_frame_to_list = data_frame_from_first_table_to_frame.groupby('pas_id').agg(tuple)['status_id'].to_list()
############################
pas_id
32250224               (3,)
34045553             (0, 1)
34045587    (0, 0, 1, 2, 3)
34045664          (0, 1, 3)
34045701             (0, 1)
34045735               (1,)
############################


# получаю в качестве списка кортежей допустимые пары значений
d_to_list =list(dict_of_right_transitions.keys()) # [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 6), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5)]

# если элемент один то добавляю элемент 666 и разбиваю исходный список статусов на пары для последующей проверки
# исходный [(3,), (0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 1, 3), (0, 1), (1,), (10,)]
def appendToOneStatusInList(statusfromframe_tolist):
    resultStatus = []
    for cort in statusfromframe_tolist:
        resultStatus.append(list((zip(cort, cort[1:] or (666,)))))
    return resultStatus
# после преобразования [[(3, 666)], [(0, 1)], [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)], [(0, 1), (1, 3)], [(0, 1)], [(1, 666)], [(10, 666)]]

#поиск несоответсвия между порлученным списком и словарем допустимых переходов из статсуса в статус
def check(listOfstatus):
    testListWithErrorStatus = []
    for item in listOfstatus:
        for i in item:
            if i not in d_to_list:
                testListWithErrorStatus.append(item)          
                print(Fore.YELLOW + '\n', 'Errors in :', i , 'from', item, '\n')             
            else:
                pass
    return testListWithErrorStatus
```

И вот дальше мне нужно получить те статусы, которые не подходят к списку допустимых статусов, и получить их id в фрейме

Comment: Вопрос до конца не понятен, сделайте минимально воспроизводимый пример. Видно нелогичности - когда датафрейм преобразуется в список и производится работа с ним с помощью циклов??? Рассмотрите возможность выборки по условию прямо из фрейма данных.

Comment: @СергейКох, разве можно сравнить фрейм и словарь? В словаре хранятся разрешенные последовательности статусов. Например `(1,2)` можно, а `(4,1)` нельзя. Плюс статус может быть только один.